# Why I'm receiving this an error TemplateDoesNotExist?

Tags: python, django

I'm receiveng this an error and I can't figure out why:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /products/
products/product_list.html
```

My code:

```
#from django.views import ListView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from .models import Product

class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    tempalate_name = "products/list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context)
        return


def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = { 
        'qs': queryset
    }
    return render(request, "products/list.html", context)
```

As you can see, I have nowhere mentioned a path: `products/product_list.html`, I'm using `products/list.html`.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: `tempalate_name` is a typo here, or in your code too ?

Comment: O my god. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a spelling error in `tempalate_name`. Try changing

```
tempalate_name = "products/list.html"
```

to

```
template_name = "products/list.html"
```

Does that help?

---

Looking at the [`ListView` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and the example on that page it seems that the default template name is `model_name` + `_list.html`; I suspect that is why Django was looking for a `product_list.html` template.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for this question. I spent 40 minutes on solving this problem and could not see it.

Comment: But, I can not understand why it makes an error? I can name it how do I want it, no?

Comment: @test_qweqwe I edited my answer to include a possible explanation.